# Overloading postfix operator ++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I have overloaded the prefix version of operator ++. How can I overload the postfix version if the overloaded function is NOT a member of my class*?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Number{
    int number;
public:
    Number(int inNr):number(inNr){}
    friend void operator++(Number& fst);
};

void operator++(Number& fst){
    fst.number=fst.number+1;
}

int main(){
    Number nr1(1);
    ++nr1;
    //nr1++; error: no 'operator++(int)' declared for postfix '++' 
}
```

*I understand if it is a member of the class, I can use the **dummy int** parameter to distinguish them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Non-member overloads also use a dummy `int` parameter to distinguish them:

```
friend void operator++(Number&);      // prefix
friend void operator++(Number&, int); // postfix
```

Note that some people might expect these to emulate the behaviour of the built-in operator by returning, respectively, the new and old values:

```
Number& operator++(Number& fst) {
    fst.number=fst.number+1;
    return fst; // reference to new value
}

Number operator++(Number& fst, int) {
    Number old = fst;
    ++fst;
    return old; // copy of old value
}
```

Comment: @MooingDuck: I didn't feel like judging; I'd be happy enough with `void`, since I don't like to do two things at once. Maybe I'll add a note about more traditional behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

I believe (I can't test this out at the moment) you use the dummy int as a second parameter to  the operator overload, i.e.

```
void operator++(Number& fst, int /*dummy*/){
    fst.number=fst.number+1;
}
```